Blockchain on EKS ( HLF Fabric ) - orderer Pod in the Crashloopback state
I'm encountering an issue while migrating my Hyperledger Fabric (HLF) deployment from a production (prod) EKS cluster to a staging (stage) EKS cluster. Both clusters are intended for blockchain purposes, using HLF fabric.
Background:
I have two EKS clusters: prod and stage. Each cluster is configured for blockchain using HLF fabric.
I have taken volume snapshots of the orderer and peer, each around 1000GB in size.

Migration Process:

I migrated the configurations of HLF deployments, including secrets, TLS certificates, and all related HLF configurations, from prod to stage.
In the stage cluster, I initially set up the HLF configurations with empty data.
Then, I created volumes from the volume snapshots of prod.
Next, I manually modified the stateful sets of the orderer and peer.
PV successfully bound, and peer pods successfully ran.

However, the orderer pod entered a crash loopback state.
Additional Information:
Prod EKS cluster version: 1.24
Stage EKS cluster version: 1.24

I have attached the logs of the crashed orderer pod for reference.
2024-04-09 06:48:31.494 UTC [orderer.common.cluster] updateStubInMapping -> INFO 023 Allocating a new stub for node 1 with endpoint of orderer1.uro.com:7050 for channel urosystemchannel
2024-04-09 06:48:31.494 UTC [orderer.common.cluster] updateStubInMapping -> INFO 024 Deactivating node 1 in channel urosystemchannel with endpoint of orderer1.uro.com:7050 due to TLS certificate change
2024-04-09 06:48:31.494 UTC [orderer.common.cluster] updateStubInMapping -> INFO 025 Allocating a new stub for node 2 with endpoint of orderer2.uro.com:7050 for channel urosystemchannel
2024-04-09 06:48:31.494 UTC [orderer.common.cluster] updateStubInMapping -> INFO 026 Deactivating node 2 in channel urosystemchannel with endpoint of orderer2.uro.com:7050 due to TLS certificate change
2024-04-09 06:48:31.495 UTC [orderer.common.cluster] func1 -> INFO 027 1 exists in both old and new membership for channel urosystemchannel , skipping its deactivation
2024-04-09 06:48:31.495 UTC [orderer.common.cluster] func1 -> INFO 028 2 exists in both old and new membership for channel urosystemchannel , skipping its deactivation
2024-04-09 06:48:31.495 UTC [orderer.common.cluster] Configure -> INFO 029 Exiting
2024-04-09 06:48:31.495 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] start -> INFO 02a Restarting raft node channel=urosystemchannel node=3
2024-04-09 06:48:31.495 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] becomeFollower -> INFO 02b 3 became follower at term 18 channel=urosystemchannel node=3
2024-04-09 06:48:31.495 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] newRaft -> INFO 02c newRaft 3 [peers: [], term: 18, commit: 20, applied: 0, lastindex: 21, lastterm: 18] channel=urosystemchannel node=3
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x10 pc=0x905447]

Any insights into why the orderer pod is crashing would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Once I encountered a TLS-related issue, we properly restored all secrets from the production cluster to the staging environment.
The network channel configuration set up in the production environment is the same as the one configured in the staging environment.

